# COBOL COMP-3 number format issue

Tags: format, cobol, bcd, ebcdic, comp-3

I have a cobol "tape format" dump which has a mixture of text and number fields.  I'm reading the file in C# as a binary array (array of byte).  I have the copy book and the formats are lining up fine on the text fields.  There are a number of COMP-3 fields as well.  The data in those fields doesnt seem to match any BCD format.  I know what the data should be and I have the raw bytes of the COMP-3.  I tried converting to EBCDIC first which yielded no better results.  Any thoughts on how a COMP-3 number can be otherwise internally stored?  Below are three examples of the PIC, the raw data and the expected number.  I know I have the field positions correct because there is alpha data on either side of the numbers and that all lines up correctly.

First Example:
The PIC of the field is 9(9) COMP-3
There are 5 bytes to the data, the hex values are 02 01 20 91 22
The resulting data should be a date (00CCYYMMDD).  This particular date should be 3-17-14.

Second Example:
The PIC of the field is S9(3) COMP-3
There are 2 bytes to the data, the hex values are 0A 14
The resulting value should be between 900 and 999
My understanding is that the "S" means that the last nibble should be 0xC or 0xD to indicate + or -

Third Example:
The PIC of the field is S9(15)V99 COMP-3
There are 9 bytes to the data, the hex values are 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 80 0C
The resulting value should be 12.00

Ok so thanks to the people who responded as they pointed me in the right direction. This is indeed an ASCII/EBCDIC representation issue. The BCD is stored in EBCDIC. Using an ASCII to EBCDIC conversion table yields properly formatted BCD digits:

I used this link to map the data: http://shop.alterlinks.com/ascii-table/ascii-ebcdic-us.php

My data: 0A 14 Converted: 25 3C (turns out that 253 is a valid value, spec was wrong) C = +, all good

My data: 01 80 0C (excluding leading zeros) Converted: 01 20 0C 12.00 C = +, implied 2 digits in format, all good

My data: 02 01 20 91 22 Converted: 02 01 40 31 7F 2014/03/17 (F is unused nibble), all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks to both people who responded as they pointed me in the right direction.  This is indeed an ASCII/EBCDIC representation issue.  The BCD is stored in EBCDIC.  Using an ASCII to EBCDIC conversion table yields properly formatted BCD digits:

I used this link to map the data: http://shop.alterlinks.com/ascii-table/ascii-ebcdic-us.php

```
My data:    0A 14
Converted:  25 3C  (turns out that 253 is a valid value, spec was wrong) C = +, all good

My data:    01 80 0C  (excluding leading zeros)
Converted:  01 20 0C  12.00  C = +, implied 2 digits in format, all good

My data:    02 01 20 91 22
Converted:  02 01 40 31 7F     2014/03/17  (F is unused nibble), all good
```

Thanks again for the two above answers which led me in the right direction.

Comment: As noted above, the solution was to convert the EBCDIC fields back to ASCII using the code page translation at the link above and then apply the standard comp-3 mapping logic.  The first two suggestions led me in the right direction but both had slight  issues in their translations which make them not technically correct because they concluded that an EBCDIC to ASCII mapping was still resulting in bad values which is in fact not correct.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a `COBOL "tape format"` although the phrase may mean something to the person who gave you the data.

The clue to your problem is that you can read the text. Connect that to the EBCDIC tag and your reference to C#.

So, you are reading data which is originally source from a Mainframe, most likely an IBM Mainframe, which uses EBCDIC instead of ASCII.

COBOL does not have native support for BCD.

What some kind soul has done for you is "convert" the data from EBCDIC to ASCII. Otherwise you wouldn't even recognise the "text".

Unfortunately, what that means for any binary or packed-decimal or floating-point fields (you won't see much of the last, but they are COMP-1/COMP-2) is that "convert" means "potentially scrambled", because the coversion is assuming individual bytes, with simple byte values, whereas all of those fields have conventional coding, either through multiple bytes or non-EBCDIC values or both.

So: COMP-3 PIC 9(9). As you say, five bytes. It is unsigned, so the rightmost nybble will be F (all bits on). You are slightly out with your positions due to the sign position being occupied, even for an unsigned field.

On the Mainframe, it contains a value `X'020140317F'`. Only that field in its entirety can make any sense as to its value. However, the EBCDIC to ASCII conversion has made it X'0201209122'.

How?

Look up the EBCDIC value of `X'02'` and `X'01'`. They don't change. Look up the value of `X'40'`, whoops, that's a space, change it to ASCII `X'20'`. Look up the value of `X'31'`. Actually nothing special there, and it has converted to something higher than `X'7F'`, but if you look at the translation table used, I guess you'll see why it happens. The `X'7F'` is a double-quote, so gets changed to `X'22'`.

The other values you show suffer the same problem.

You should only ever take data from a Mainframe in character-only format. There are many answers here on this, you should look at the `related` to the right.

Have a look at this recent question: [Convert COMP and COMP-3 Packed Decimal into readable value with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346634/convert-comp-and-comp-3-packed-decimal-into-readable-value-with-c)

Comment: So first thanks to everyone for the arduous work and thorough answers here so far.  I did try an EBCDIC code page translation, both manually and using the C# translation function and ran into similar issues as noted above (e.g. non mapping characters).  Unfortunately the data provider (in this case First Data) will not modify the format provided.  The "tape format" refers to the title of the document, just in case any FDR people out there might know about this.  This one happens to be format '20' which lays out data about card charges for credit issuers.

Comment: Unfortunately the specification is confidential and cannot be posted online.  However it does not contain any clues about which EBCDIC code page this is stored in.  I've lobbed another call into them to see if I can figure that out, but it sounds like this is an EBCDIC translation issue at this point.

Comment: As an aside - this is a standardized (albeit confidential) format used by the industry, so there is some magic sauce somewhere that will convert these scrambled characters.  Other people have successfully loaded this file and this file is produced per a heavily documented specification that has been around for, literally, decades.

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's have a look at your first example. Given the format and value the original BCD-content should have been something like

```
02 01 40 31 7F
```

When transforming that from EBCDIC to ASCII we run into trouble with the first, second and fourth byte because they are control-characters - so here we would need some more details on how the ASCII->EBCDIC-converter worked. Looking at the two remaining bytes those would be changed

```
EBCDIC     ASCII     CHARACTER
40      -> 20        (blank)
7F      -> 22         "
```

So assuming the first two bytes remain unchanged and the third gets converted like `31->91` we end up with

```
02 01 20 91 22
```

which is what you got. So it looks like some kind of EBCDIC->ASCII-conversion took place. If that is the case it might be that you can't repair the data since the transformation may not be one-one and thus not reversible.

Looking at the second example and using

```
EBCDIC     ASCII     CHARACTER
25      -> 0A        (LF)
3C      -> 14        (DC4)
```

you would have started with `25 3C` which would fit the format but not the range you gave.

In the third example the original `01 20 0C` could be converted to `01 80 0C` since `20` also is an EBCDIC control-character with no direct ASCII-equivalent.

But given all other examples I would assume there is some codepage-conversion issue.
If you used some kind of filetransfer to move the data fromm the (supposed) mainframe make sure it is set to binary-mode and don't do any character-conversion before you split the file into fields and know what's meant to be a character and what not.

EDIT: You can find a list of several EBCDIC and ASCII-based codepages [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/globalization/cp/cp_cpgid.html) or look [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pcomhelp/v5r9/topic/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/reference/pdf/hcp_referenceV58.pdf) for the same as one pdf.

Comment: As I said: the X'91' is just an assumption - since X'31' has absolutly no meaning in EBCDIC it might be mapped to anything. Looking at our terminal-emulations translation-tables it would be mapped to X'2D' as most of the other values in that area, but all kinds of strange things can happen...

Comment: Something that might help the community (and me haha) is a link or repost of available EBCDIC code pages and their mappings.  I've found several scraps of things online but nothing definite.  There is a high probability that this indeed an IBM mainframe.  I did some contract work for the vendor (First Data) a while back and it was all IBM there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm coming to this a bit late, but have a couple of suggestions that might make your life easier...

First, see if you can get your mainframe conterparts to convert all non-character (i.e. binary numeric and packed decimal) data 
to display format (e.g. PIC X) before you
download it. Then you only need to deal with the "printable" range of numeric characters representing 0 through 9. Printable character
only code-page conversions are fairly standaard and tend not to screw up as much. Reformatting data given a copybook is not
a difficult prospect for anybody
proficient in a mainframe environment. Unfortunately, sometimes you get the "runaround" and a claim is made that it is
extremely costly or, takes special software, or any one of a hundred other bogus excuses.

If you get the "runaround" then the next best thing is to is download the file in binary format and do your own codepage conversion 
for the character data (fairly
straight forward). Next deal with the binary data based on your copybook definitions. With a few Googles you should be able to find
enough information to get through converting the PACKED-DECIMAL (COMP-3) data to whatever you need.

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

[Numeric Data Formats](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/IGY3PG31/1.3.4?DT=20060329003636)

[Packed Decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packed_decimal#Packed_BCD)

I do not recommend trying to reverse engineer the code page conversions applied by your file transfer package in order to
decode the packed decimal and other binary data.

Answer (score -2):

You can avoid the above issues by having the data converted into a modern method for transferring data: XML.

Comment: Unfortunately the provider drives the business, and in fact most of the industry, and they do not care about providing translations.  The point of the question, and the exercise, was to find a solution for EBCDIC packed comp-3 numbers, which I eventually did.